# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a python script which has a pretty simple function to pull data from database, then processing it with pandas and then insert back to database, batch by batch. It was running perfectly fine at the very begining, but after serverl loops, it suddently crushed, shows

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819
```

It is this line make the process exit, but it run successfully in in the begining of the loop.

```
df.to_sql(name='TABLE', con=xx_engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

I tried searching for answers as much as I can, but have not been able to find one. Can anyone help?

Comment: What version of python are you using? Try to upgrade to the newest version and see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone if you have encounter this issue whiling using `pd.to_sql`, please check if you have set `fast_executemany=True` when creating your engine. If you set that to `False`, you will see an Error Message instead, for my case, it was an arithmetic overflow.